# Necessary and sufficient condition for the oriented area of a triangle to be positive

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus

I'm tryng to solve the following problem from Edwards'*Advanced
Calculus: A Differential Forms Approach*.

> Give a necessary and sufficient condition for the oriented
> area of the triangle $(0, 0), (x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)$ to be positive.
> [The equation $y_1x - x_1y = 0$ is the equation of the line
> through $(0, 0)$ and $(x_1, y_1)$. The sign of the number $y_1x - x_1y$
> tells which side of this line the point $(x, y)$ lies on.]

The book's answer says that the oriented area is positive if, and only if, $x_1y_2 - x_2y_1 > 0$; which can be seen from the fact that the oriented area of $(0, 0), (x_1, y_1), (-y_1, x_1)$ is positive.

I can see that, but how does one prove the *general* case? How can I explicitly derive the fact that "The sign of the number $y_1x - x_1y$ tells which side of this line the point $(x, y)$ lies on"?

(I considered an argument involving the determinant, but it felt circular).

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are asking. You know the *statement* of the necessary and sufficient condition, and you are asking how to *prove* it?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry it was not clear. I'd like to know how to prove that is the necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: It is not quite clear: would you like to prove that two points with the same sign of $y_1x−x_1y$ lie in the same half-plane or determine from the sign the half-plane where a given point lies.